# How can I combine the following information into 1 mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

**DETAILS**

I want to find the difference between start and stop times(duration) for each test taken then rank users according to the highest score and lowest duration for each test. Ultimately I will use PDO to do this in mysql. So far though I've just been working on the sql. I think I'm pretty close now, but am unsure `how to combine the information into one query`.

**WHAT I'VE GOT(untested).**

I have the following table called `testresults`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| index | id |         start         |          stop        | score| 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   | 23 |   2012-06-06 07:30:20 | 2012-06-06 07:30:34  | 100  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my select statement I want to get the `id` and the `score` along with the calculated `duration`.

I can get duration for any test taken today with the below query.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,stop,start) AS duration
FROM testresults WHERE `start` >= DATE(NOW())
```

Then I sort the results based on rank. Rank is determined according to score and duration. Top place goes to the highest score with the shortest duration.I believe I can do that with something like this:

```
ORDER BY score DESC, duration ASC
```

I only want maybe 100 entries so,

```
LIMIT 100
```

**QUESTION**

How can I combine the above information into 1 query?

Comment: What happens when you put it all together i.e., `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,stop,start) AS duration
FROM testresults WHERE 'start' >= DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY score DESC, duration ASC LIMIT 0,100`?  It look right.

Comment: I don't know how to put it together. This is a complex query for me.

Comment: If you can link me to a similar query I can probably work it out though.

Comment: I thought this was more complex than it was. For some reason I thought I had to wrap part of this query in brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`, `score`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( SECOND, start, stop ) AS `duration`
FROM `testresults`
WHERE `start` >= DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY `score` DESC, `duration` ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

This will work pretty good. You'll also need to put `id` & `score` in `SELECT` statement.

Comment: This did it for me but with one change `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,start,stop) AS duration` It seems I had it round the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, score, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,stop,start) AS duration FROM testresults
WHERE `start` >= DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY score DESC, duration ASC LIMIT 100
```

this should work